# Use of "set down" in a formal document

Tags: style, word-choice

I was recently asked to translate a Spanish letter of recommendation into English. Not being an English native speaker, I was bound to make a few mistakes. According to a reviewer, one of these was the following use of the phrasal verb "set down":

"**I, (name of signee), am pleased to *set down* in this document that ...**"

The tone is meant to formal but somewhat relaxed, as the document is not legal binding.

Is this wrong syntax? Should I have used some other verb?

Comment: What was the reasoning provided for it being wrong? I can think of no such reason myself, but maybe I'm just missing it.

Comment: "Set down" is archaic and formal. It sounds a bit like someone phrasing the US constitution. It's beautiful language, but not in common usage. It might work in a legal document. This document seems fairly formal, but it's not the phrase I'd use. I'm not an english major, so I can't say with certainty what is common usage in this kind of business document. Sorry.

Comment: I googled it up, and yes, I found very few modern instances - so you have a point there. I might have used some other simple verb, like "state". Thanks for your help.